# Browser can't find my CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, ckeditor, richfaces

I am working on an web application which uses jsf and richFaces. I am trying to use the latest version of CKEditor. It works properly in other projects but in that one, the CKEditor is replaced by RichFaces's CKEditor and I don't want that. If I find any CKEditor (latest version)file in the server directory, I can find it but in the development mode of my browser that folder doesnt appear and I think that is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell RichFaces to use your files instead of the ones it comes with, create "META-INF/richfaces/static-resource-mappings.properties" and put something like this in there:

```
org.richfaces.ckeditor\:ckeditor.js=myCKEditor/ckeditor.js
```

But bear in mind that the rich:editor might not work with newer versions of CKEditor (although currently the newest is 4.7 compared to 4.5.8 so it should work).

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. The property that I wrote is: org.richfaces.ckeditor\:ckeditor.js=http://localhost:8080/sp_crm_web/resources/webeditor/ckeditor.js. I have tried without the localhost:8080 too, but the RichFaces CKEditor still appears.

Comment: The path should be relative to the resource folder - `webeditor/ckeditor.js`

Comment: I tried it too but my CKEditor does not appear. The first solution that I have found is to remove the CKEditor embedded in richfaces-xxx.jar and it is working. But I have to replace that .jar each time that I deploy the server and that is not a good solution.